# Wordpress theme is not appearing

Tags: wordpress-theming

I installed a new theme in WordPress. When I go to activate this theme from dashboard, I got all previously and currently installed theme is lost. Now it is showing only one theme which is currently active. I am working on localhost. What's the matter?

Comment: I don't think Stack Overflow is the right place for this question. Try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Comment: How did you install it? Where did you download the theme form?

Comment: I download it from http://demo.wpcharity.com/paper/. I simply download this theme in zip format, then extract this and put this in themes folder.